# Cache Slick DBIO Actions

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, hikaricp, play-slick

I am trying to speed up "SELECT * FROM WHERE name=?" kind of queries in Play! + Scala app. I am using Play 2.4 + Scala 2.11 + play-slick-1.1.1 package. This package uses Slick-3.1 version.

My hypothesis was that slick generates Prepared statements from DBIO actions and they get executed. So I tried to cache them buy turning on flag **cachePrepStmts=true** 
However I still see "Preparing statement..." messages in the log which means that PS are not getting cached! How should one instructs slick to cache them?

If I run following code shouldn't the PS be cached at some point?

```
for (i <- 1 until 100) {
  Await.result(db.run(doctorsTable.filter(_.userName === name).result), 10 seconds)
}
```

Slick config is as follows:

```
slick.dbs.default {
  driver="slick.driver.MySQLDriver$"
  db {
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/staging_db?useSSL=false&cachePrepStmts=true"

    user = "user"

    password = "passwd"

    numThreads = 1  // For not just one thread in HikariCP

    properties = {
      cachePrepStmts = true
      prepStmtCacheSize = 250
      prepStmtCacheSqlLimit = 2048
    }
  }

}
```

**Update 1**

I tried following as per @pawel's suggestion of using compiled queries:

```
val compiledQuery = Compiled { name: Rep[String] =>
  doctorsTable.filter(_.userName === name)
}


val stTime = TimeUtil.getUtcTime
for (i <- 1 until 100) {
  FutureUtils.blockFuture(db.compiledQuery(name).result), 10)
}
val endTime = TimeUtil.getUtcTime - stTime
Logger.info(s"Time Taken HERE $endTime")
```

In my logs I still see statement like:

```
2017-01-16 21:34:00,510 DEBUG [db-1] s.j.J.statement [?:?] Preparing statement: select ...
```

Also timing of this is also remains the same. What is the desired output? Should I not see these statements anymore? How can I verify if Prepared statements are indeed reused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL you need to set an additional jdbc flag, `useServerPrepStmts=true`

HikariCP's [MySQL configuration page](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration) links to a quite useful document that provides some simple [performance tuning](http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/21/Connector_J%20Performance%20Gems%20Presentation.pdf) configuration options for MySQL jdbc.

Here are a few that I've found useful (you'll need to `&` append them to jdbc url for options not exposed by Hikari's API). Be sure to read through linked document and/or MySQL documentation for each option; should be *mostly* safe to use.

```
zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&characterEncoding=UTF-8
rewriteBatchedStatements=true
maintainTimeStats=false
cacheServerConfiguration=true
avoidCheckOnDuplicateKeyUpdateInSQL=true
dontTrackOpenResources=true
useLocalSessionState=true
cachePrepStmts=true
useServerPrepStmts=true
prepStmtCacheSize=500
prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
```

Also, note that statements are cached per thread; depending on what you set for Hikari connection `maxLifetime` and what server load is, memory usage will increase accordingly on both server and client (e.g. if you set connection max lifetime to just under MySQL default of 8 hours, both server and client will keep N prepared statements alive in memory for the life of each connection).

p.s. curious if bottleneck is indeed statement caching or something specific to Slick.

*EDIT*

to log statements enable the query log. On MySQL 5.7 you would add to your `my.cnf`:

```
general-log=1
general-log-file=/var/log/mysqlgeneral.log
```

and then `sudo touch /var/log/mysqlgeneral.log` followed by a restart of mysqld. Comment out above config lines and restart to turn off query logging.

Comment: Thanks for your response. At the moment I am purely curious as to if prepared statement caching works at all or not in Slick + Hikari combo. I just wonder in JDBC how can I verify if preparedstatement are cached or not?

Comment: with server-side statement caching enabled the mysql query log will show a single prepare + execute for initial query, followed by only executes for all subsequent cache hits for the target statement. If you add `useServerPrepStmts=true` you should see this pattern in the log.

Comment: I tried that. Actually do you know how can I turn on mysql query logging? I turned on slick logging and that always shows `Preparing statement: select ...` kind of logs no matter what. This statement comes from JdbcBackend.scala: https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/074002eb6290c0742ab28135c8109b3465311b81/slick/src/main/scala/slick/jdbc/JdbcBackend.scala#L301  so that creates confusion

Comment: Awesome thanks so much! I can see prepare statements in action now. Interestingly just using compiled queries and without using any server side caching is actually 9 to 11% faster

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Compiled` queries - which are exactly doing what you want.

Just change above code to:

```
val compiledQuery = Compiled { name: Rep[String] =>
    doctorsTable.filter(_.userName === name)
}

for (i <- 1 until 100) {
  Await.result(db.run(compiledQuery(name).result), 10 seconds)
}
```

I extracted above `name` as a parameter  (because you usually want to change some parameters in your `PreparedStatement`s) but that's definitely an optional part.

For further information you can refer to: http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.0/queries.html#compiled-queries

Comment: Aha! Let me check that and get back to you. Thanks for this very useful observation :) By the way do you have any comments on my slick config? Do you think `properties` object is redundant since I specify JDBC url?

Comment: I am not sure if its working! I did a timing of this loop with and without compiled query and its comes out to almost same. I see `Preparing statement: select user_name, ...` messages coming  from this file: https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/074002eb6290c0742ab28135c8109b3465311b81/slick/src/main/scala/slick/jdbc/JdbcBackend.scala how can I make sure that prepared statements are actually getting reused?

Comment: You sure you have `val compiledQuery` and not `def compiledQuery` ?

Comment: Yeah its `val` for sure. Do you know what kind of logs am I suppose to see if it works as expected?

Comment: there must be some error earlier, now after gaining more clarity on server side logging and config parameters, I can see that compiled queries are faster. Thanks for your help!