# How to optimize scala REST api using AKKA-HTTP, spray-json, oauth2 and slick?

Tags: scala, rest, akka-http, slick-3.0

I've created an REST api in scala using `AKKA-HTTP`, `spray-json` and `Slick`. For Authorization of route, I've used `oauth2`.

DAO to retrieve Data(Using Plain SQL):

```
def getAllNotes: Future[Seq[UserEntity]] = {
    implicit val getUserResult = GetResult(r => UserEntity(r.<<, r.<<, r.<<, r.<<, r.<<, r.<<))
    query(s"select id, email, password,created_at, updated_at, deleted_at from users", getUserResult)
}
```

DAO to retrieve Data(Slick Table):

```
def getAll(): Future[Seq[A]] = {
    db.run(tableQ.result)
}
```

Here's the part of routing:

```
val route: Route = pathPrefix("auth") {
    get {
        path("tests") {
            complete(userDao.getAll.map(u => u.toList))
        } ~
        path("test") {
            complete(userDao.getAllNotes.map(u => u.toList))
        } ~
        path("testUsers") {
            baseApi(userDao.getAllNotes)
        } ~
        path("users") {
            baseApi(userDao.getAll())
        }
    }
}

implicit def baseApi(f: ToResponseMarshallable): Route = {
    authenticateOAuth2Async[AuthInfo[OauthAccount]]("realm", oauth2Authenticator) { auth =>
        pathEndOrSingleSlash {
            complete(f)
        }
    }
}
```

Functionally, all routes are working as intended but the performance seems to be degrading when OAUTH2 and Slick Tables are used for getting data.

The respective results of above routes:

```
1. "users"     => 10 request per second: OAUTH2: YES, Slick Table: YES
2. "testUsers" => 17 request per second: OAUTH2: YES, Slick Table: NO
3. "tests"     => 500 request per second: OAUTH2: NO, Slick Table: YES
4. "test"      => 5593 request per second: OAUTH2: NO, Slick Table: NO
```

**My Problem**

How can I optimize the REST request using OAUTH2 and Slick Table?

Would it be good practice if I used PLAIN SQL instead of Slick tables and Joins in all cases?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that enabling Oauth2 has the biggest impact, however the overhead added by akka http is negligible compared to the network/service call done on oauth2Authenticator. Even if it is done in async manner you still need to configure correctly the execution context (good read [Explaining AKKA Thread Pool Execturor Config parameters](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/eR4fShuWm6w)).

In regards to the Slick part it seems that you declare the implicit row mapper on each request (can be a class val property).
Take a look at the [Compiled Queries](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#compiled-queries) and make sure that you allocate enough jdbc connections in your db connection pool configuration.

In any case the whole concept of this test does not seem very useful, one should have the minimal requirements(ex: min 100 requests/second) and then start building on top of that.

Comment: By implicit row mapper on each request, do you mean `userDao.getAll.map(u => u.toList)`. Any example or code snippet would be good enough to analyze. :)

Comment: I was refering to the `implicit val getUserResult` in `getAllNotes` method, that can be declared at the class level instead.

Comment: I replaced the implicit and the achievement I received is `5926 rps`. And How could I use Compiled in `getNotes()`? I tried db.run(Compiled(tableQ)) but that generated errors

Comment: in the `getAllNotes` you use a `query` function that takes a string and a row mapper, I assume that in it you use something like `db.run(sql(plainQuery))`, since you query is without parameters you can also declare it at the class level as val notesQuery=Compile(sql"select .. from users")) and then in `getAllNotes` use `db.run(notesQuery)`...

Comment: do you have any other implementation idea for OAuth2 in Scala

Answer (score 0):

Part regarding `Slick` has been answered multiple times. Most recent answer is here: [Cache Slick DBIO Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648817/cache-slick-dbio-actions/41660548#41660548)

This should dramatically improve response times for plain `Slick` version.

I can't help you with `OAUTH2` though :/